# UnicodeDecodeError utf8 codec Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I have built a scraper which reads `artistnames` from a csv file and collects `artistdata` via the `Songkick` api from these artists. However, after running my code  for a while I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 64-65: invalid continuation byte
```

Sample data can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/emq2vijnjw47uc5/Sampleartistdata.csv?dl=0):

I am relatively new to coding and I was wondering how can I solve this error? Below you can find my code.

```
            import urllib2
            import requests
            import json
            import csv

            from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
            db = TinyDB('spotify_artists.json')

            #read csv
            def wait_for_internet():
                while True:
                  try:
                    resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com', timeout=1)
                    return
                  except:
                    pass

            def load_artists():
                    f = open('artistnames.csv', 'r').readlines();
                    for a in f:
                        artist = a.strip()
                        print(artist)
                        url = 'http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?query='+artist+'&apikey='
                        # wait_for_internet()
                        r = requests.get(url)
                        resp = r.json()
                        # print(resp)
                        try :
                          if(resp['resultsPage']['totalEntries']):
                            # print(json.dumps(resp['resultsPage']['results']['artist'], indent=4, sort_keys=True))
                            results = resp['resultsPage']['results']['artist'];
                            for x in results:
                            #   print('rxx')
                            #   print(json.dumps(x, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

                              if(x['displayName'] == artist):
                                print(x)
                                db.insert(x)

                        except:
                          print('cannot fetch url',url);



            load_artists()
            db.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rmlj\Dropbox\songkick\scrapers\Data\Scraper.py", line 45, in <module>
    load_artists()
  File "C:C:\Users\rmlj\Dropbox\songkick\scrapers\Data\Scraper.py".py", line 25, in load_artists
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 474, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 407, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 302, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 358, in prepare_url
    url = url.decode('utf8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 64-65: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of your error? My guess is that there is an encoding mismatch when parsing the JSON...

Comment: The problem is more likely in your input data - are you trying to read ISO-8859-x (or some other non-UTF-8 encoding)?

Comment: Yes, there are also some artist names in my input data which seem to have non-UTF-8 characters in their artist names. I know that I have some chinese and japanese artists in it as well. Does that maybe cause problems?

Comment: What encoding is `artistnames.csv` saved in? Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: I have saved it in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: This problem can't be reproduced without the input file. [mcve]

Comment: Sample data has been uploaded

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your formation of a URL where you pass the query string as `bytes` (regular `str` on Python 2.x) with characters in a non-utf-8 encoding to the `requests` module, which in turn tries to turn it into an utf-8 unicode string, and fails.

First of all, you should let the `requests` module form your query string and deal with the creation of your final URL:

```
url = "http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json"
r = requests.get(url, params={"query": artist, "apikey": ""})
# etc.
```

But second, you should not mix encodings least you want to be in a world of hurt. Unfortunately, the built-in `csv` module doesn't work with Unicode which is probably why you end up with invalid characters. To remedy that, install [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv) and use it as a drop-in replacement (just replace your `import csv` with `import unicodecsv as csv`).

**update**: Wait, on a second look you're not even using csv. You're reading your file line by line and trying to pass that off as a query. Is that your intended behavior? If that's the case, keeping with the idea of staying with same encoding:

```
import codecs

URL = "http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json" # no need to redefine this

with codecs.open("artistnames.csv", "r", "utf-8") as f:
    for a in f:
        artist = a.strip()
        r = requests.get(URL, params={"query": artist, "apikey": ""})
        # etc.
```

Comment: As I am not that experienced with coding I am also not sure if my current method of reading line by line and query the artist name is the best way to go. All in all, my intended behavior is to get artist data for every name in csv (which is basically just a csv with only one collumn called artists and on every row an artist name. Is there a better way to do this compared what I am doing now?

Comment: Well, if it's a single column file it's not technically a CSV (there are no separated values to speak of ;)) so reading it line-by-line as presented above is perfectly fine. You might want to skip the first line, tho, as it would contain the column name - just add `next(f)` before `for a in f:`. Also, make sure your `artistnames.csv` is saved in UTF-8 encoding so you don't get a mismatch when trying to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use unicode whenever possible. Requests should convert any non-ascii characters in the url to the correct encoding.

```
>>> import requests  

>>> requests.get(u'http://Motörhead.com/?q=Motörhead').url  
u'http://xn--motrhead-p4a.com/?q=Mot%C3%B6rhead'
```

As you can see, the domain name is encoded as [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), and the querystring uses [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

as long as `artist` is a valid unicode string, this should work.

```
url = u'http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?query='+artist
```

if `artist` is a byte string, you must decode it into unicode using the correct encoding, which depends on what your original input file was encoded as.

```
artist = artist.decode('SHIFT-JIS')
```

Comment: If I try to use this solution I end up with the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128) Does that mean that I have to decode like in your example about artist as a byte string?

Comment: If it's uft8, then decode as utf8 (not ascii, not shift-jis). If you don't understand how python 2 handles unicode, why don't you use python 3 instead?

Comment: It's impossible for us to know which encoding is correct, since you have not shared the input file.